# Using allure with xUnit

Tags: teamcity, xunit, xunit.net, allure

Did anyone tried to use Allure reports for xUnit tests solution? I'm in doubts because there is no xUnit in the list of supported adapters(https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-core/wiki#gathering-information-about-tests). I have installed Allure teamcity plugin but there is no any allure output in the artifacts. If someone used Allure teamcity plugin with xUnit please explain how to set it up. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post your "UPDATE" as an answer, and edit it out of your question with the "edit" link.

Comment: if you post that as an answer, you can accept your own answer to close this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allure support confirmed that there is no xUnit support for now. So the only way is to create custom adapter for xUnit

Answer (score 3):

To display xUnit tests on .NET Core in allure reports you can use this [Open Source library](https://github.com/TinkoffCreditSystems/Allure.XUnit).
It's custom adapter. This library based on Allure.Commons.
It's project with examples using this library: https://github.com/TinkoffCreditSystems/Allure.XUnit/tree/master/src/Examples

You must mark you test methods by this library attributes. Instead `[Fact()]` attribute you must use `[AllureXUnit()]` attribute, and you can use other unrequired attributes for  markup html-report. All exists attributes were descripted in library [Readme](https://github.com/TinkoffCreditSystems/Allure.XUnit/blob/master/Readme.md).

Than you must run tests by command:

```
dotnet test <PathToYourProject>
```

After that json files will be generated in directory which you specify in  "directory" field of `allureConfig.json`. You can build html report by command `allure serve` or by allure plugins in TeamCity from this json files.

Comment: I created a small project with 2 unit tests. When these tests were attributed by [Fact] attribute, everything worked well. I followed the recommendations above, replaced attributes with [AllureXUnit], installed required nuget projects (Allure.XUnit and Allure.Commons) and re-run "dotnet test ". 
Eventually I received message "No test is available in ... Make sure that test discoverer & executors are registered and platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again."
Please advise - what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Allure2 do support xunit project. It does not require a adapter but you can simply generate allure reports from xunit xml reports. 
Steps taken for .netcore2 xunit test project.

1. Generated output xunit xml report with command: dotnet test --logger:trx
2. Generated Allure report with command: 
   allure serve /home/path/to/project/target/surefire-reports/ 
   *(Refer docs to install allure commandline - docs.qameta.io/allure/latest/#_installing_a_commandline)*